# OST File Recreating

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I just upgraded to new Laptop and my .ost file is 4.5 GB(Exchange server) and I backed up my OST file and tried to recreate the Outlook with my old OST file.

But receiving an error as

> Outlook is using an old copy of your ost

I tried searching for an answer - everyone says delete the OST file Outlook will automatically create a new one but the issue is Internet in my location is very slow to download 4.5 GB it will take Days.

Can Anyone please help on this matter. Windows 8.1 pro with Office 13..

Comment: Delete and rebuild your OST file. Set your Outlook to download headers first then body. You don't need to access all your e-mails at once. You can also search for them using the Exchange server, so not a big deal it takes days to sync it all. You can also take your computer to a location that has faster internet.